# making a Django chatbot application interact with multiple users

Tags: python, mysql, django

i have a django chatbot application on web faction shard host. the idea is : the chatbot application simulate the customer service in chatting with the customers.

Basically the conversation will be exchanged through the API using GET and POST, where it first POST the input then GET calls the python file to SELECT the input form the DB and process it then update the database with the retrieved out put.Finally a GET is used to fetch the out put and display it.

so far it is working for one user at a time, what i am considering now is that i want it to chat with multiple customer at the same time an isolating each user.

Do i have to use Redis just for the chatting part, if yes how i can merge it in my project? other there are other solution out there?

i have developed it using:

**python3:** for the chatbot code.

**Django:** for the website.

**Mysql:** for the data base, that hold the knowledge based for the chatbot such as a table that include number of input and it correspond output.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

There is a whole chatbot solution based on Python 3 + Django + Mongo/sqlite. Its github link is https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot. Hope it can help you.
This repository also contains Django application example: https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/tree/master/examples/django_app

Answer (score 1):

You can use Redis,Celery,Python RQ,Rabbit MQ  as a queue for distributed tasks(chatting tasks) in your Django app. But this will increase complexity in your project. I will recommend you to Develop Python based multi client chat server.

Comment: Thank you for the help. May i ask about developing a multi client chat server, do you mean that i have to redevelop the application? and do you mean a multithreaded server?

Comment: Yes, you have to redevelop the application with multithreaded feature

Comment: Unfortunatly  i don't have the time to redevelop it, is there any other solutions?

Comment: Use django's multi session package, multiple users can access your application at a time. You can integrate this in short time https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multi-sessions

Comment: one more method , use python sub-process which will help you to create 'n' number of chatbots which can serve multiple clients